# How to use group by to have parent-child fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
title - description
 A          AA
 B          B
 A          AAA
 B          BBBBB
```

now I would like to have a json like this:

```
A
  AA
  AAA
B
  B
  BBBB
```

Is it possible to use one query?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I used simple join and group by but them didn't work.

Comment: `order by title`, after the first iteration don't output the `title` again until it changes.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian - Conversion to JSON string should be done in your application code.

Comment: @GurV I just to show the output.

Comment: It's good. Is the first item as a parent?

Comment: Is it a JSON construction or mysql question? Mysql answer, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90b052/2. Then iterate over the `group_concat(description)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you can use `group by` with `group_concat` to get comma separated value for each title:

```
select title,
    group_concat(description)
from your_table
group by title;
```